# How to remove div and input created by document.createElement with a button

Tags: javascript, function, dom, createelement

I was trying to remove div and input created by document.createElement with a button. For that, I have tried to assign a function to the button which will remove the element with the remove method. I guess I am not using the correct selector or tag, maybe this is why the button is unable to remove the element? What can I do to solve this?

//This is the code I used-

```
function myFunction() {
  var btn = document.createElement("div");

  btn.innerHTML = " Magic div";
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
}


function myFunction1() {
var newElement = document.createElement('input');

document.body.appendChild(newElement);
}
```

//This is what I have tried-

```
function myFunction5a() {
  var myobj1 = document.getElementById("div");
  myobj1.remove(btn);
}

function myFunction1a() {
  var myobj2 = document.getElementById("input");
  myobj2.remove();
}
```

//used these buttons-

```
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="myFunction5a()">Remove it</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="myFunction1()">Click me too</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="myFunction1a()">Remove me too</button>
```

Comment: What's the relation between your button and the div? Both are getting appended to the body. Are they adjacent? If so, you can make use of `nextElementSibling`.

Comment: @WaisKamal Thanks for your comment, no they are separate. what can be done in that case?

Comment: In this case you need to keep track of them, for example by storing them in an array or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

use setAttribute to put class and use either querySelector or getElementsByClassName and then use remove.

I am just giving an example below code

```
function myFunction() {
  var btn = document.createElement("div");
btn.setAttribute("class", "magicDiv");   //use setAttribute to assign class

  btn.innerHTML = " Magic div";
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
}


function myFunction1() {
var newElement = document.createElement('input');
newElement.setAttribute("class", "inputItem");  //use setAttribute to assign class
document.body.appendChild(newElement);
}


function myFunction5a() {
  var myobj1 = document.getElementsByClassName("magicDiv"); //query selector can also be used
  myobj1.remove(btn);
}

function myFunction1a() {
  var myobj2 = document.getElementsByClassName("inputItem");  //query selector can also be used
  myobj2.remove();
}
//used these buttons-

<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="myFunction5a()">Remove it</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="myFunction1()">Click me too</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="myFunction1a()">Remove me too</button>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, but after using them I am getting this error-test.html:66 Uncaught ReferenceError: btn is not defined
    at myFunction5a (test.html:66)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (test.html:27)
myFunction5a @ test.html:66
onclick @ test.html:27
test.html:71 Uncaught TypeError: myObj2.remove is not a function
    at myFunction1a (test.html:71)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (test.html:29)